# Enable animation with blend using property binding condition

Tags: wpf, storyboard, expression-blend

I am working with blend 4,
I am trying to play some StoryBoard using ControlStoryBoardAction with the contidion: if a specific Border Element in my UC has greater width then 250.

I set the next configuration:
[image: Set data binding]

[image: Config ControlStoryBoardAction]

And when I run my application I am getting the following error:

LeftOperand of type "OpeningViewModel" cannot be used with operator "GreaterThan".
  Source=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions

What I am doing wrong?
How can I launch StoryBoard with element property condition?

Comment: I am not familiar with Blend, but obviously you're trying to check if your OpeningViewModel is greater than 250, which cant be right. I think you should choose the ActualHeight of your border1 in the orange bordered field.

Comment: You right, I don`t know why the blend created me this binding. I found How to config it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I did wrong.
When you choose property value to bind, you need do it thro"Element Property binding...".
I used "Data Binding" and this is the reason it raised an exception.

[image]